# Windows 10 taskbar missing icons after scaling

Tags: windows, windows-10, taskbar, icons, scaling

I have a new Windows 10 device at work and its doing fine. For better usability I changed the display scaling from 100% to 110%. Using the new scaling, some icons are not displayed on the taskbar any more. In fact, the icons do exist, but are "too far right". Instead of having

| (network icon) (sound icon) (messages central icon) (clock) |

I just got

| (network icon) (clock) |

You can see it also here:

[image: current taskbar]

How can I get my icons (espacially sound) back while still having display scaling?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: dont you show hidden icon. did u check in it

Comment: I checked it already - the icon is activated in the settings - it shows up on 100% scaling - it does not show up on 110% scaling

Comment: Did you reboot after changing the scaling?

Comment: yes - rebooted after each scaling change

Comment: Have you tried disabling the icons, press ok, then enabling the icons, press ok again?

Comment: yes - I checked everything. When deactivating the icons, other icons disappear - the most right ones.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a miscalculation in the Windows code.  I had the same problem and fixed it by tweaking the scaling slightly; in my case changing it from 110% to 111% solved the problem.

Comment: The problem has been present since the release of Windows 10 and is still the case in Windows 10 1809. At this point you may start to wonder whether they actually care about these kind of issues at all.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I added some extra icons to the taskbar i didn't use anyway. The ones you add last will stay, while the first few will disapear.

Comment: I don’t know what issue you had, but I doubt that it’s the same one.  The OP wants hidden icons to appear.  You have presented a way to make icons disappear — the exact opposite!  Can you explain any way that this actually answers the question?